# How can the data entered by a user get updated in the database in Django?

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, checkbox

This is my html code for checkbox :

```
<div class="col">
                <div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="formCheck-1"><label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-1" style="color:rgb(255,255,255);">Melody</label></div>
                <div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="formCheck-1"><label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-1" style="color:rgb(255,255,255);">Rock</label></div>
                <div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="formCheck-1"><label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-1" style="color:rgb(255,255,255);">Classical</label></div>
                <div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="formCheck-1"><label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-1" style="color:rgb(255,255,255);">Jazz</label></div>
                <div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="formCheck-1"><label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-1" style="color:rgb(255,255,255);">Metal</label></div>
            </div>
```

Views.py (I am very new to programming, so the code could be wrong)

```
def Userregister(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    Name = request.POST['Name']
    Melody = request.POST.getlist['Melody']
    Rock = request.POST.getlist['Rock']
    Jazz = request.POST.getlist['Jazz']
    Classical = request.POST.getlist['Classical']
    Metal = request.POST.getlist['Metal']
```

models.py

from django.db import models

```
class User(models.Model) :
Name= models.CharField(max_length=100)
Melody = models.BooleanField(default=False)
Rock = models.BooleanField(default=False)
Jazz = models.BooleanField(default=False)
Classical = models.BooleanField(default=False)
Metal = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: Where did you find to use these methods? check out the Django tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/. To complete what you are trying you'd ideally use a form class so that Django handles most of the backend for you. Then use class based views for simplicities sake and use form_valid which will then allow you to handle the data easily https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, I think by adding something like

`User.objects.create(name=request.POST['Name'], melody=request.POST.getlist['Melody'], etc)`

it should save to the db but read my comment above, and follow those links as they'll help you a lot to use much nicer Django tools